# how to store and get access_token in NextJS SSR

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, jwt, next.js

I use NextJS with ServerSide Rendering

I use an authentication service with access_token (JWT)

I can't store access_token in the `localStorage` because it's not available in the `getServerSideProps`

so I put access_token in an `httpOnly cookie` to be available on the server.

I have some requests on the server and some on the client, so I need to get the access_token in two ways, on the server from `req.headers.cookie` and on the client from `document.cookie`

I want to wrtie axios interceptors to add access_token to the every request.

this works for the client-side, but what can I do for the server-side ?

```
import axios from 'axios';

const _axios = axios.create();
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  let token;

  // check if it's on the client-side
  if(typeof document !== 'undefined')
     token = getToken(document.cookie);

  // how to check for server-side and how to get cookie ?

  return {
    ...config,
      headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  };
}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

export default axiosInstance;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [nookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nookies)

From getServerSideProps

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {

    //Parse cookies from request header
    const cookies = nookies.get(ctx)

    //Set cookies on response header
    nookies.set(ctx, 'key', 'token', { path: '/' })

    ...

}
```

From API route

```
export default function handler(req, res) {

    //Parse cookies from request header
    const cookies = nookies.get({ req })

    //Set cookies on response header
    nookies.set({ res }, 'key', 'token', { path: '/' })

    ...
}
```